# Python Dataframe Linear Regression every column being emptied?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, linear-regression

I'm working with Pandas & Numpy to create a Linear Regression model to predict the gross of movies.
I'm able to successfully import the dataset and drop the columns I'm not using, and convert the ones I am into float64. This leads to some columns having NaN as values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn

df1 = pd.read_csv("sample_data/imdb_top_1000.csv",header = 0)
moviedata=df1.drop(["Poster_Link","Released_Year","Overview"], axis = 1)

moviedata['Runtime'] = moviedata['Runtime'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*min', expand=False)

moviedata['Series_Title'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Series_Title'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Certificate'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Certificate'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Runtime'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Runtime'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Genre'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Genre'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['IMDB_Rating'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['IMDB_Rating'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Meta_score'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Meta_score'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Director'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Director'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Star1'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Star1'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Star2'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Star2'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Star3'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Star3'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['Star4'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Star4'], errors='coerce')
moviedata['No_of_Votes'] = moviedata['No_of_Votes'].astype(float)
moviedata['Gross'] = pd.to_numeric(moviedata['Gross'], errors='coerce')
print('\nShape of data :',moviedata.shape)

OUTPUT: Shape of data : (1000, 13)
```

I used this line in a previous assignment to remove NaN values in a dataset:

```
moviedata = moviedata[~(np.isnan(moviedata).any(axis = 1))]
print('\nShape of data :',moviedata.shape)

OUTPUT: Shape of data : (0, 13)
```

However, when I use it this time, it removes every row value in the dataset, leaving me with 0 rows & 13 columns.
Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

A link to the dataset:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zaMz2J7GVf24MtSEgoKn6uZOO0Uvldh4vzJqKw1aBTM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: when using ```pd.to_numeric``` with coerce=True, all the values that cannot be converted into numbers, will return 'NaN'. Therefore, when you remove all the NaN values, you'll remain with very few lines, considering that about all values in the columns 'director', 'genre', 'title', etc. do not contain number and thus will be converted to NaN.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html, you set Series_Title and Certificate columns to NaN, by setting errors=coerce (If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.)

Comment: Then should I set it to 'ignore' to keep the column values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: errors ='ignore', Where both text and numbers are given.
There are other ways of preprocessing, you just need to know what you need it for.